# Calling a function at object deletion in Haskell

Tags: c++, haskell, garbage-collection, ffi

I'm writing a Haskell wrapper for a C++ class. I decided to represent it as a Haskell Data structure containing a pointer (Foreign.Ptr) to the class instance in C++. Something like that.

In C++:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    double my_method();

    // ...
};

extern "C" MyClass* cpp_new_MyClass() {
    return new MyClass();
}

extern "C" double cpp_my_method(MyClass *obj) {
    return obj->my_method();
}
```

In Haskell:

```
Data MyClass = MyClass (Ptr ())

foreign import ccall "cpp_new_MyClass" cppNewMyClass :: Ptr () 
foreign import ccall "cpp_my_method" cppMyMethod :: Ptr () -> Double

mkMyClass :: MyClass
mkMyClass = MyClass cppNewMyClass

myMethod :: MyClass -> Double
myMethod (MyClass ptr) = cppMyMethod ptr
```

The problem is, I don't know how to correctly implement MyClass deletion. At some point, Haskell garbage collector will delete MyClass object, but it won't trigger MyClass* memory freeing in C++. How do I fix that?

I'm aware of [ForeignPtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html), but it uses `IO` monad, which is not satisfying because I want the wrapped data structure to behave exactly as a normal Haskell data structure, without the need for explicit allocating/freeing memory or `IO` monads.

Comment: Is your class side-effect free? If not, as it is common in C++, you _have_ to use the `IO` monad, or _carefully_ ensure you are exposing a pure interface to that. That, or lose referential transparency, which is a deadly sin in Haskell since it will make the behaviour of the program almost impossible to predict, especially when the optimizer rewrites your code assuming it.

Comment: @chi Yes, it is side-effect free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> “it uses `IO` monad, which is not satisfying because I want the wrapped data structure to behave exactly as a normal Haskell data structure”

Sure you do, but unfortunately it's not really possible. Foreign “functions” can always do funny stuff that shouldn't be possible in Haskell; the type system has no way to look there and prevent it.

That dilemma is the only (!) reason we have `unsafePerformIO`, and indeed yours is a good example of a valid application for that thing.

I haven't done this myself yet, but your code should look something like the following:

```
extern "C" void cpp_delete_MyClass(MyClass* obj) {
    delete obj;
}
```

```hs
foreign import ccall "cpp_new_MyClass" cppNewMyClass :: IO (Ptr ())
foreign import ccall "&cpp_delete_MyClass" cppDeleteMyClass :: FunPtr (Ptr () -> IO ())

data MyClass = MyClass (ForeignPtr ())

mkMyClass :: MyClass
mkMyClass = unsafePerformIO $ do
   newObj <- cppNewMyClass
   fPtr <- newForeignPtr cppDeleteMyClass newObj
   return $ MyClass fptr
```

I'm not quite sure about those `FunPtr`s, hopefully somebody will comment something about that...

Comment: I thought of such solution using `unsafePerformIO` on `ForeignPtr`, but I'm not sure it will work correctly. If you are, can you please explain what is going on behind the scenes in that approach?

Comment: @wrwt Every time `mkMyClass` is evaluated (should be only once, but don't rely on that) a C++ object is allocated, a Haskell value is created with a finalizer attached to that, and returned as a pure value. When one of such values is garbage collected, the finalizer (`cppDeleteMyClass`) will be run.

Comment: About `FunPtr`s. The correct way to declare `cppDeleteMyClass` is `foreign import ccall "&cpp_delete_MyClass" cppDeleteMyClass :: FunPtr (Ptr () -> IO ())` (with & added). You probably should fix your answer.

Comment: You should put a NOINLINE on `mkMyClass` if you want to guarantee that `cppNewMyClass` will be called only once (though it sounds like the OP might not need such a guarantee in this case).